# appending 2 columns into one list in sql

Tags: sql, database

I have 2 tables and each table has some 3 columns. i want to get one column such that one column from each table are apended one after the other

```
 eg:- suppose one column in a table contains  hai, how, are, you.
 and another column in another column contains i, am, fine.
 i want a query which gives hai, how, are, you,i,am,fine. in just one column
```

can anybody give a query for this in sql...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your schema correctly you have this

```
Table1:  Column1
          hai,
          how,
          are,
          you.

Table2: Column2
          i,
          am,
          fine.
```

Do This:

```
Insert Into Table1 (Column1)
Select Column2 From Table2
```

You will get this:

```
Table1: Column1
         hai,
        how,
        are,
        you.
         i,
        am,
        fine.
```

If you have 3 Columns
Then just do this:

```
Insert Into Table1 (Column1, Column2, Column3)     //the (Column1, Column2, Column3) is not neccessary if those are the only columns in your Table1
Select Column1, Column2, Column3 From Table2       //the Select Column1, Column2, Column3 could become Select * if those are the only columns of your Table2
```

EDIT: Do this if you don't want to modify any tables.

```
Select Column1, Column2, Column3
From Table1
UNION ALL
Select Column1, Column2, Column3
From Table2
```

Comment: but you are modifying the column in table 1 which is not what i intended... need a way without modifying the data in database.

Comment: yes.. i just want to display in the above mentioned format without modifying the database

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear. One interpretation of it is that you want to UNION the two:

```
select column
from table1
union
select column
from table2;
```

If you really want all rows from both tables (and not the distinct values), UNION ALL will be faster than UNION.

If you want the rows in a certain order be sure to specify an ORDER BY clause.